# Get column value from string column name sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is this possible to get multiple columns value when we have column name as string 
Like if i have a table `Test` and i have columns `FirstName , LastName , Address` .

Now what i want to get value of all three columns but i want to make this dynamic so that i just pass string column name i get values for that columns

**Example**

```
Select 

(select column_name from metadata )

from source table
```

Comment: your question is not clear, can you add an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the column names as parameters

```
DECLARE @COLS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @COLS = 'COL1,COL2'
SET @TABLE = 'TABLENAME'
```

Now execute the query

```
DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @QRY = 'SELECT (SELECT '+@COLS+' FROM '+@TABLE+') FROM sourcetable'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QRY
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build the query in code dynamically. However it needs to be robust so that it does not gets prone to SQL injection. Something like this:

```
string commandString = "select {0} from SomeTable";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = string.Format(commandString, "selected column names");
command.EndExecuteReader();
```

In SQL:

```
declare @query nvarchar(500)

set @query  =  replace('select 0 from author','0','column names from some parameter') 

execute sp_executesql @query
```

Update 2: Does this do what you need?

```
declare @query nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @columnNames varchar(1000)

set @columnNames = ''
SELECT @columnNames = @columnNames + column_name  + ',' FROM metadata
set @query  =  replace('select 0 from source_table','0',SUBSTRING(@columnNames,0,LEN(@columnNames)-1)) 

execute sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: I want to do this in t-sql

Comment: From where would you pass column names to SQL?

Comment: Check the updated reply. If you can post some code, it will be quick to help.

Comment: replace('select 0 from author','0',@columnNames) is just a fancy way to write 'select '+@columnNames+' from author'. That doesn't get you any safety.